# How can background and popup connect when using webpack

Tags: google-chrome, webpack

I am using webpack to develop a chrome extend, webpack.config.js can looks like this:

```
  entry: {
    background: ['babel-polyfill', './src/background'],
    content: ['babel-polyfill', './src/content'],
    popup: ['babel-polyfill', './src/popup'],
  },

  output: {
    filename: '[name].js',
    path: path.resolve('./dist/'),
    publicPath: '/',
  },
```

The webpack build files to directory--dist and I set them in the mainifest.json for chrome to use. However I found that because of webpacks' building, dist/background and dist/popup.js cannot connect as before:

```
// popup.js
var bg = chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage();
bg.test()
```

I wanna pass some vars from popup.js to background.js, What can I do in such situation?

Answer (score 0):

I just used the chrome storage API to solve this problem. Both background and popup are sharing the same storage. 
As for the common functions, put them in the same javascript file and import it in background and popup using webpack will be fine.